# shell request failed on channel 0 putty

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I'm trying to pull from bitbucket through Jenkins in our AWS windows server. Jenkins is using the System User so I need to accept the host key in order for it to work because Jenkins doesn't provide user input for me to enter yes. I used `psexec` command to run cmd as System User, then opened git bash from there so that I can use it as a System User. I then tried 
`putty -ssh git@ourURLthatwasProvided -P 7999` and recieved this error

```
Discounnecte: No Supported Authentication methods availbale
shell request failed on channel 0
```

I am not sure what that means. After researching online, I tried this command to see if it was connecting

```
ssh -Tv git@ourURLthatwasProvided -P 7999
```

In the log, it says

```
Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authentication to bitbucket
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
shell request failed on channel 0
```

Any help is appreciate it.